# How to stop Vim from creating *-e files

Tags: vim

Recently my Vim has been littering my folders with extra files ending with `-e`. For example, if I'm editing a file called `test.php`, sometimes (but not always!) I'll wind up with another file called `test.php-e` as well.

I have no idea what's causing this, but it's fairly annoying. I haven't changed anything recently, as far as I can tell. The backup files all wind up in my `~/.vim/backups` directory, so I'm not sure where these things are coming from. Thoughts?

Comment: does it happen to all files? e.g. *.txt, *.py, *.*? or only for php file? are you sure the -e files are not the tmp/swap file from other editor?

Comment: @Kent I've only ever noticed with .php files, but that could be because I write primarily php files. And I'm not using any other editor, so I don't think that's it either.

Answer (score 2):

```
set nobackup
```

or set backup dir to something like /tmp and purge from time to time.

From VIM docs (:help nobackup)

```
'backup' 'bk'       boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Make a backup before overwriting a file.  Leave it around after the
    file has been successfully written.  If you do not want to keep the
    backup file, but you do want a backup while the file is being
    written, reset this option and set the 'writebackup' option (this is
    the default).  If you do not want a backup file at all reset both
    options (use this if your file system is almost full).  See the
    |backup-table| for more explanations.
    When the 'backupskip' pattern matches, a backup is not made anyway.
    When 'patchmode' is set, the backup may be renamed to become the
    oldest version of a file.
    NOTE: This option is reset when 'compatible' is set.
```

Comment: this seems not the solution OP is looking for... he said he reconfigured backups to a certain dir.

Comment: Setting nobackup in the running editor/global .vimrc is one of the quickest ways to avoid them. You can configure vim to write everywhere, but what if you got no w access to that directory ?

Comment: Right, all the other backups wind up in `~/.vim/backup`, so in my hypothetical example there is also a `test.php~` file in my backup dir. I wouldn't mind if these `-e` files were in the backup directory, but they make all of my working directories pretty messy.

Comment: @MichaelM. that seems to exclude VIM from the culprit list. Are you using some kind of versioning ? Opening this -e files show you the actual file ? diffing with the original shows some hints ? (I'm thinking about them being swaps)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what else it would be. I'm using Git, but I'd never noticed it being a problem before switching to Vim (I'm a relatively recent convert). The -e files appear to be, as far as I can tell, identical to the non-e versions.

Comment: I'm using git too (for a C project) and never noticed anything. You can check in the .git/hooks directory, there are a couple of initialization scripts, run each time you work on a file (checkout/commit/push), maybe there's something there.

Comment: Aha! Something dubious in my pre-commit hook was doing it if there were whitespace errors. I think I added that hook about the same time I started using Vim, which would explain my confusion. Thanks @BigMike!